# Improving typesetting of sums with long limits

Tags: math-mode, spacing

This piece of code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{s=n-t+1}^{j-1}}s-(n-t)=\sum_{s=1}^{j-1-(n-t)}s=\frac{\bigl(j-1-(n-t)\bigr)\bigl(j-(n-t)\bigr)}{2}\]
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

I’d like to have

[image]

commands like `\smashoperator` or `\mathclap` are of no use as the width of the upper limit is correctly pushing the equal signs apart. How can I give TeX a hint that I want to move the summand s close to the sigma and under the upper limit?

Comment: Not quite understood, `\smashoperator` smashes both upper and lower limit. Or is what you are asking for, that if the summand is short, then the with of the limits should still be taken into account? That case is IMO too special to make a makro for it, I would just pull back the `s` by hand.

Comment: If the middle sum would stand on its own `\smashoperator` would do the job. But here the `=` should not move under the upper limit only the `s`. How do I move the `s` easily? What commands are there to achieve this?

Comment: Ugly Hack: You can always insert some negative horizontal space just before `s` i.e. `\hspace{-2ex}s`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{s=n-t+1}^{j-1}}s-(n-t)=
 \mathop{\sum_{s=1} s}^{j-1-(n-t)}=\frac{\bigl(j-1-(n-t)\bigr)\bigl(j-(n-t)\bigr)}{2}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: haha, yes, ofcourse!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe if you make the `\sum s` a single `\mathop` entity:

```
\let\hw\hidewidth
$$
  \sum_{\hw s=n-t+1\hw}^{j-1} s-(n-t)
  =\mathop{\sum s}_{s=1}^{j-1-(n-t)}={\bigl(j-1-(n-t)\bigr)\bigl(j-(n-t)\bigr)\over2}
$$
\bye
```

Comment: Then the lower limit is centered incorrectly.

Comment: @uli: Oh, bummer. You could stuff a `\enspace` (or something along that size) at the end of the lower limit, but it's ugly.

Comment: or you could use `\mathop{\phantom{s} \sum s}` and then the limits will be centered because the new operator is "symmetrical."