# How does \smashoperator clip the space of limit scripts?

Tags: math-mode, macros, mathtools

There already are question about how to smash math operator limits horizontally, e.g. [Improving typesetting of sums with long limits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39182/improving-typesetting-of-sums-with-long-limits), with the conclusion "use the `\smashoperator` command from the `mathtools` package".

I'm trying to understand how this macro works. Unfortunately, [the implementation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.dtx) is `expl3`-obfuscated and thus hard to understand. There are some comments on the code but there's almost no description of how internal macros are to be used. What I understand so far is that `\smashoperator` first analyses its mandatory argument and splits it into superscript, subscript and some other, optional code.

What I don't understand is how the operator is actually typeset with scripts smashed only on the left, right or both sides. Could someone explain in TeX/LaTeX2e code how this part of the command is implemented?

Comment: As far as I understand it, it is put in a box of width 0 pt.

Comment: Actually it isn't mathtools is not written in expl3, is written in a self contained dialect of what became the expl3 syntax

Comment: It uses a lot of strangeness (that I don't understand either) to figure out exactly what type of data it has been given (no limits, just bottom limit etc), then gathers up these arguments to it knows what the operator is, and the limits, then typeset this which the limits in an internal version of clap

Comment: I'm guessing it would be a lot simpler to implement these days with xparse and the e type (for handling the parsing of the arg given to smashoperator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off:

```latex
\newcommand*\smashoperator[2][lr]{
  \def\MT_smop_use:NNNNN {\@nameuse{MT_smop_smash_#1:NNNNN}}
  \toks@{#2}
  \expandafter\MT_smop_get_args:wwwNnNn
    \the\toks@\@nil\@nil\@nil\@nil\@nil\@nil\@@nil
}
```

Upon calling `\smashoperator{\sum_{a}^{b}}`, the macro `\MT_smop_use:NNNNN` is defined to expand to `\MT_smop_smash_lr:NNNNN` and the argument is loaded in the token register `\toks@`. It's not really clear why doing this intermediate step, because the token register's content is immediately delivered and we get

```latex
\MT_smop_get_args:wwwNnNn \sum_{a}^{b}\@nil\@nil\@nil\@nil\@nil\@nil\@@nil
```

The purpose of `\MT_smop_get_args:wwwNnNn` is to identify the operator, the subscript and the superscript, with very long code. Then the superscript and subscript are set in boxes with the appropriate cramped style and placed above and below, but occupying zero width.

A simpler implementation with `xparse`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\xsmashoperator}{me{_^}}{%
  \doxsmashoperator{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\doxsmashoperator}{mmm}
 {
  #1
  \IfValueT{#2}{\sb{\mathclap{\cramped{#2}}}}
  \IfValueT{#3}{\sp{\mathclap{\cramped{#3}}}}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
XXXX\smashoperator{\sum_{k=12345^2}^{123456789}}YYYYYY \\
XXXX\xsmashoperator\sum_{k=12345^2}^{123456789}YYYYYY
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It would be more complicated to implement also the `l` and `r` options, but the main ingredients are already there, namely how to absorb optional subscript and superscript, without even requiring additional braces (which are not allowed in the `xparse` version).

Note that `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` are not required; they're used in view of the implementation of `l` and `r`.

Basically one needs to do the measuring and to add the necessary spacing fore or aft. Let *sp*, *sb* and *op* be the widths of the superscript, subscript and the operator, respectively. The operator is then set to its normal width with super-/subscripts of zero width. If `r` is set, a space of width max(0pt, max(*sp*, *sb*) - *op*) / 2 is added before the operator; if `l` is set, it's added after the operator.

Here's a complete implementation:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\xsmashoperator}{ome{_^}}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {%
    \doxsmashoperator{#2}{#3}{#4}%
   }
   {%
    \doxsmashoperatoropt{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
   }
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\doxsmashoperator}{mmm}
 {
  #1
  \IfValueT{#2}{\sb{\mathclap{\cramped{#2}}}}
  \IfValueT{#3}{\sp{\mathclap{\cramped{#3}}}}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\doxsmashoperatoropt}{mmmm}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \__siracusa_xsmashoperator:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
  \group_end:
 }

\box_new:N \l__siracusa_xsmashoperator_op_box
\box_new:N \l__siracusa_xsmashoperator_sb_box
\box_new:N \l__siracusa_xsmashoperator_sp_box
\dim_new:N \l__siracusa_xsmashoperator_dim

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__siracusa_xsmashoperator_math:n
 {
  $ \use:c { m@th } #1 $
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__siracusa_xsmashoperator:nnnn
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__siracusa_xsmashoperator_op_box
   {
    \__siracusa_xsmashoperator_math:n { \displaystyle{#2} }
   }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__siracusa_xsmashoperator_sb_box
   {
    \tl_if_novalue:nF { #3 }{ \__siracusa_xsmashoperator_math:n {\scriptstyle\cramped{#3}} }
   }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__siracusa_xsmashoperator_sp_box
   {
    \tl_if_novalue:nF { #4 }{ \__siracusa_xsmashoperator_math:n {\scriptstyle\cramped{#4}} }
   }
  \dim_set:Nn \l__siracusa_xsmashoperator_dim
   {
    \dim_max:nn
     { \box_wd:N \l__siracusa_xsmashoperator_sp_box }
     { \box_wd:N \l__siracusa_xsmashoperator_sb_box }
    - \box_wd:N \l__siracusa_xsmashoperator_op_box
   }
  \dim_set:Nn \l__siracusa_xsmashoperator_dim
   {
    \dim_max:nn { \l__siracusa_xsmashoperator_dim } { 0pt } / 2
   }
  % now do the typesetting
  \str_if_eq:nnT { #1 } { r } { \hspace{\l__siracusa_xsmashoperator_dim} }
  #2
  \tl_if_novalue:nF { #3 } { \sb{\mathclap{\cramped{#3}}} }
  \tl_if_novalue:nF { #4 } { \sp{\mathclap{\cramped{#4}}} }
  \str_if_eq:nnT { #1 } { l } { \hspace{\l__siracusa_xsmashoperator_dim} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
XXXX\smashoperator{\sum_{k=12345^2}^{123456789}}YYYYYY \\
XXXX\xsmashoperator\sum_{k=12345^2}^{123456789}YYYYYY \\
XXXX\smashoperator[l]{\sum_{k=12345^2}^{123456789}}YYYYYY \\
XXXX\xsmashoperator[l]\sum_{k=12345^2}^{123456789}YYYYYY \\
XXXX\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{k=12345^2}^{123456789}}YYYYYY \\
XXXX\xsmashoperator[r]\sum_{k=12345^2}^{123456789}YYYYYY
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the spacing calculation isn't obvious at first sight. Why is the `\cramped` command used here for the limits? Does that give the same limits as in the non-smashed version?

Comment: @siracusa I used the same method as `mathtools`, but actually TeX *doesn't* use the cramped style in the upper limit. It's easy enough to remove `\cramped` in two places.